# how to implement client-server model to compute matrix multiplication in android

Tags: android, client-server, matrix-multiplication, computation

I have designed a mobile application to compute matrix multiplication but it works for limited size. So, I want to redesign matrix multiplication app so that it can compute for a large dimension(5000*5000) using **client-server** model where we will send input files to the server and server will return output file to the client. I don't know how to design client-server model in android so please suggest me how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a server script that receives the input files, ($_GET or $_POST), do the computation and returns result in JSON( you can also use xml, but i prefer JSON for light weight) format.
I hope the following site can help you

[1]   [Android Development: Implementing a simple Client-Server model](http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2010/09/android-development-implementing-a-simple-client-server-model/)

[2]   [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)